# xQuery delete nodes based on list of values for single attribute

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, xquery, xquery-sql

Let's say we have this simple `XML` structure:

```
<myXML>
    <data>
        <column value="1" />
        <column value="2" />
        <column value="3" />
        <column value="4" />
        <column value="5" />
        <column value="6" />
        <column value="7" />
        <column value="8" />
        <column value="9" />
        <column value="10" />
    </data>
    <data>
        <column value="1" />
        <column value="2" />
        <column value="3" />
        <column value="4" />
        <column value="5" />
        <column value="6" />
    </data>
    <data>
        <column value="3" />
        <column value="4" />
        <column value="5" />
        <column value="6" />
        <column value="7" />
    </data>
</myXML>
```

I need to remove all nodes from a specific list of values, for example (1,4,6,8,9), by using the `XML` `modify` statement.

Right now I'm using the following statement (it is build dynamically):

```
myXML.modify('delete for $Node in /data/column where ($Node/[@value=1]) or ($Node/[@value=3]) or ($Node/[@value=4]) return $Node')
```

But when I have big list of values it slows down the performance of my query.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: How big is your XML file?  how many individual <data> nodes and how many children average are those <data> nodes expected to have?  I tend to lean toward shredding into a table.  Doing your modifying in SQL and then putting it back into XML using FOR XML.

Comment: My XML can be from 10 to 1000 individual <data> nodes. In my case those <data> nodes can have 2 children max and in their children's there is no restriction of values( they can be 1 to 1000 or even more). At the time i make this delete my biggest XML is like 50 000 lines or so.

Answer (score 0):

where $Node/value = (1, 2, 3, 9, 12)

will be true if value is 1, is 2, is 3, is 9 or is 12

Comment: and what if i have bigger CSV of values (like 400-500 values) - will that worse the performace ?